# How to forbid a specified github account to commit codes to projects on git

Tags: git, github

My private github account is bound to the company's projects.  Is there anyone who knows how to remove my private account from the company's projects so that my private account has no permission to commit code to the company's projects?

Comment: Ask the developer who maintains your company's GitHub  organization to revoke the write permission from your collaborator access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to push commits to each of your company's projects is called "write access" or "write permission". It is a part of ["collaborator access"](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/) which is, basically, just membership in a project on GitHub. It can be added and removed by the *maintainer* of your company's GitHub organization. So if you need just the write access to be revoked, you should ask the maintainer to do it in each project.

If you need to completely block the account from pushing to any projects and viewing private projects, you should ask the maintainer to [revoke the organization membership of the account](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization/).